# Is my circuit design correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis, high-voltage

Using this [Jacob's Ladder video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yNQQwa9bzg), I drew this circuit.  How are the red wires connected in the video? If they are indeterminate please just say so.  Looking at the side of the transformer on the right side I see the two wires: one blue wire, and one black wire.  Those two wires are the power source as told in the video, and the output of the transformer goes to the ladder itself, and then to the chassis.  The other terminal on the transformer are those two red wires, so how are they connected in the video?
[image]

Comment: Is it just me, or do I see a short circuit?

Comment: Yeah it is I was just wondering how is the other primary side connected in the video.

Answer (score 2):

The "second secondary" (2) is a low voltage (5 V - 10 V), high isolation secondary winding for the magnetron cathode heater (3).

[image]

You *really* don't want to connect that to the mains, as it would rapidly overheat the heater winding, blow the fuse and likely destroy both the primary and high voltage secondary by overvoltage at the same time.

You also don't want to short the heater winding out (as you have apparently done in your hand-drawn schematic) as doing so will drastically overload the transformer for no benefit.

I'd suggest that you stay away from this project until you know exactly what you are doing. 110 V is dangerous, 230 is nasty and 2 kV is outright lethal.

Comment: I am trying to visual understand what is the component attached to the two red wires in the transformation; however, I have an inadequacy in electronics because I only know how to work with logic gates, and logic circuits as well as Arduinos.  The PLTW Digital Electronics course I took does not really teach well enough, so any help is appreciated.  The circuit that you have included I have already looked at multiple times since I searched that circuit up to serve as a contrasting circuit to the Jacob's Ladder one.